# Action after Camera crash the app

Tags: java, android, camera

After a Picture has captured, I want to change the fragment, but the app only crash. The Importand Part of the Code is at the very end. Thanks for any Hint or Solution. Because I'm new in Java(android) development, I don't know, where my fault is.

Here is my Code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    NavigationView navigationView = null;
    Toolbar toolbar = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        main newFragment = new main();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera_light);

        int color = Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF");
        fab.setColorFilter(color);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                takePhoto();

            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            // super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

            main newFragment = new main();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            /*noVIP TextFragment = new noVIP();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, TextFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();*/
            select_type TextFragment = new select_type();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, TextFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nur Style ;)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nur Style ;)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private static final int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 1;

    private void takePhoto() {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(this)));
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
    }

    private File getTempFile(Context context) {
        final File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context.getPackageName());
        if (!path.exists()) {
            path.mkdir();
        }
        return new File(path, "image.tmp");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case TAKE_PHOTO_CODE:
                    final File file = getTempFile(this);
                    try {
                        Bitmap captureBmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file));

                        HaveTakePhoto(); //Call the Fragment Change.

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    void HaveTakePhoto() { //<--- Called after the Picture has taken.
        noVIP TextFragment = new noVIP();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, TextFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Do Stuff", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The Crash Report:

```
04-27 20:27:20.774 26944-26944/android.niklasvlach.simplegerman E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: android.niklasvlach.simplegerman, PID: 26944
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {android.niklasvlach.simplegerman/android.niklasvlach.simplegerman.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3607)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3650)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1370)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1493)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1511)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:638)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:617)
                                                                                      at android.niklasvlach.simplegerman.MainActivity.HaveTakePhoto(MainActivity.java:165)
                                                                                      at android.niklasvlach.simplegerman.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:148)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3603)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3650) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1370) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

noVIP Fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class noVIP extends Fragment {


    public noVIP() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_no_vi, container, false);
    }

}
```

PS: If I change the fragment with exact this Code at every other Time, the App not Crash.

Comment: Could you please place the crash report too ?

Comment: Now there is a crash-report above

Comment: add noVIP fragment code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling commitAllowingStateLoss() is more of a hack than a fix. State loss is bad and should be avoided at all costs. At the time that onActivityResult() is called, the activity/fragment's state may not yet have been restored, and therefore any transactions that happen during this time will be lost as a result. This is a very important bug which must be addressed! (Note that the bug only happens when your Activity is coming back after having been killed by the system... which, depending on how much memory the device has, can sometimes be rare... so this sort of bug is not something that is very easy to catch while testing).

Try moving your transactions into onPostResume() instead (note that onPostResume() is always called after onResume() and onResume() is always called after onActivityResult()):

```
private boolean mReturningWithResult = false;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mReturningWithResult = true;
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    if (mReturningWithResult) {
        // Commit your transactions here.
    }
    // Reset the boolean flag back to false for next time.
    mReturningWithResult = false;
}
```

For more details Visit [Fragment Transactions & Activity State Loss](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html)